# Saving Entity to specified table in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am implementing horizontal sharding of my database in my Symfony application. I have a method to create a table based on the "template" Entity I've made. For example, my Entity "AnswerData" will be used to create tables such as "AnswerData_sourceA", "AnswerData_sourceB"... and so on that are exact same schemas as the entity-based "AnswerData". While I have the database tables created already, I'm not quite sure how to get Symfony and Doctrine to designate which table I want the Entity to be created/saved to.

For example:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$answerData= new AnswerData();
$answerData->setData();
//Set other properties...
...
$em->persist($answerData);
$em->flush();
$em->clear();
```

The above would have Symfony/Doctrine save the Entity to "AnswerData" table, but I am not sure where/how to tell it to save it to the "AnswerData_sourceA" table. Should I be writing custom repository classes that handle this or can the above snippet be modified to manually set the table? Thank you for any advice!

Comment: It seems possible to setup connections for each shard, then determine which connection to use at runtime given the criteria for selecting the table.

Comment: did you try to add condition iin the controller? like if its for answerData_sourceA it will save in the answerData_sourceA table. then same with the B

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you want to save to specified table. you need

```
    /**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="AnswerData_sourceA")
 */
```

to specify that name like this.

Comment: That doesn't work when the application is brokering to multiple shards, e.g., `_source*` can change at runtime.